# Add subclasses of templated base-class to container without super-base-class?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'm trying to create a vector (or any STL container, really) that could hold a set of various objects that are subclasses of one specific type. The problem is that my base class is templated.

From what I can tell, I have to create an interface/abstract super base class (not sure what the preferred C++ terminology is). I'd prefer not to do this, and just use my (templated) abstract base class. Below is some example code.

Basically, is there a way not to require the `WidgetInterface`? Someway to tell the compiler to ignore template requirements? If I must have `WidgetInterface`, am I going the right way with the following?

```
#include <vector>
#include "stdio.h"

enum SomeEnum{
    LOW = 0,
    HIGH = 112358
};

// Would like to remove this WidgetInterface
class WidgetInterface{
public:
    // have to define this so we can call it while iterating
    // (would remove from Widget if ended up using this SuperWidget
    // non-template baseclass method)
    virtual void method() = 0; 
};

template <class TDataType>
class AbstractWidget : public WidgetInterface{
public:
    TDataType mData;
    virtual void method() = 0;
    // ... bunch of helper methods etc
};

class EnumWidget : public AbstractWidget<SomeEnum>{
public:
    EnumWidget(){
        mData = HIGH;
    }
    void method(){
        printf("%d\n", mData); // sprintf for simplicity
    }
};

class IntWidget : public AbstractWidget<int>{
public:
    IntWidget(){
        mData = -1;
    }
    void method(){
        printf("%d\n", mData); // sprintf for simplicity
    }
};


int main(){
    // this compiles but isn't a workable solution, not generic enough
    std::vector< AbstractWidget<int>* > widgets1; 

    // only way to do store abitary subclasses?
    std::vector<WidgetInterface*> widgets2; 
    widgets2.push_back(new EnumWidget());
    widgets2.push_back(new IntWidget());

    for(std::vector<WidgetInterface*>::iterator iter = widgets2.begin();
        iter != widgets2.end(); iter++){
        (*iter)->method();
    }

    // This is what i'd _like_ to do, without needing WidgetInterface
    // std::vector< AbstractWidget* > widgets3; 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't use directly `AbstractWidget` as a parameter of STL container or anything else. 
The reason is that class `AbstractWidget` *does not* exist. It is only a *template* for compiler to construct classes from.

What exists is `AbstractWidget<SomeEnum>` and `AbstractWidget<int>` only because of `EnumWidget` and `IntWidget` inheriting from them.

Templates exist at compiler-level only. If `AbstractWidget<T>` weren't used anywhere in your code, there would be *no traces* of it during the runtime.

Therefore, the code you posted seems to be the best (if not only) solution for your problem.

Comment: Ah I thought as much. C++ syntax has some dark corners, I thought perhaps there was a simple fix. Not that the proposed solution is reprehensible (if anything its more extensible anyway).

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is the solution: you need a *common* class/interface, and since `AbstractWidget` is class template, therefore it cannot be used as common class for all concrete classes for which the template argument is different. So I think, you should go with this class design. It seems to be quite reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the classes `AbstractWidget<int>` and `AbstractWidget<double>` are different classes, so your class IntWidget is a subclass of the first but is in no relation with the second. You need to have a common parent class to put in the vector so unfortunately you can not avoid the common interface that is not templated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be completely in the wrong direction, but could you do something like this:

```
template <class T>
class ConcreteWidget : public AbstractWidget<T>
{
};
```

and then use template specialization to define your specific widgets like this:

```
template <>
class ConcreteWidget : public AbstractWidget<int>
{
public:
    ConcreteWidget() : mData(-1) {}
};

template <>
class ConcreteWidget : public AbstractWidget<SomeEnum>
{
public:
    ConcreteWidget() : mData(HIGH) {}
};
```

So rather than having an IntWidget and an EnumWidget, you'd have a ConcreteWidget and ConcreteWidget and then could simply have a `vector<WidgetInterface>` that would be the super of all of these generic children?

I'm not sure if this solves your problem, or would even work. I'd love feedback on this answer.

Comment: So, which class would you parametrize `std::vector` with?

Comment: WidgetInterface still, so this doesn't solve his problem. But would this be considered better design that how he is defining his concrete types?

Comment: I would say *equivalent*, but it's a disputable matter.

Comment: Thats an interesting idea.

Not really applicable for me because realistically I have things like LEDWidget, MomentaryWidget, POTWidget. LED and Momentary both use the same datatype but are represented and behave differently.

Comment: But couldn't you use template specialization as shown above to separate the behaviors?

Comment: Not really, 

`template<> class ConcreteWidget : public AbstractWidget<SomeEnum>{custom-led-code};
template<> class ConcreteWidget : public AbstractWidget<SomeEnum>{custom-momentary-code};`

There's no difference class signature-wise between the two even though their behavior varies (yet both use the same datatype). I could see where you're solution would be useful for other cases though.